# App can't read xml file from android but can read from pc

Tags: c#, android, xml, unity-game-engine

So i have this code and my questions are not stored in any folder. It's just there in the assets. And the problem is that when i build the app and i open it from any android phone won't display the questions. Sorry for my english.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameUtility {

    public const float      ResolutionDelayTime     = 1;
    public const string     SavePrefKey             = "Game_Highscore_Value";

    public const string     FileName                = "Q";
//file name is upthere and the dir down

    public static string    FileDir                 
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.dataPath + "/";
        }
    }
}
//this gives me a new question

[System.Serializable()]
public class Data
{
    public Question[] Questions = new Question[0];

    public Data () { }

    public static void Write(Data data, string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
        }
    }
    public static Data Fetch(string filePath)
    {
        return Fetch(out bool result, filePath);
    }
    public static Data Fetch(out bool result, string filePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath)) { result = false; return new Data(); }

        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var data = (Data)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);

            result = true;
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to know why my app won't display my questions from android? On pc works preety fine.

Comment: Does the file exist on you Android device? Do you get an error message when running on Android?

Comment: Looks like this line of code isn't needed since you are reading from a stream.  Remove :  if (!File.Exists(filePath)) { result = false; return new Data(); }  You also need to read from stream instead of opening a file.  Do you have a memory stream?

Comment: when running on android no error. i have tried to remove this line . ill be back with an update

Comment: this didnt work. i dont have  memory stream i think. i dont even know what is that.

Answer (score 0):

Android files are compressed within the APK, therefore you need a different way to open them. You can try the following code.

```
    string xml;
#if UNITY_EDITOR || !UNITY_ANDROID
    xml = File.ReadAllText(StreamingXmlPath);
#else
    // compressed in android (not readable with File).
    WWW reader = new WWW (StreamingXmlPath);
    while (!reader.isDone) {}
    xml = reader.text;
#endif
```

Comment: actually i'm very new to programming so i need some more help implementing your code in mine :)

Comment: The code loads the whole content of the file into the variable `xml`. From there you need to deserialize it into a `Data` object. You can test if this code helps you by logging `xml` and check the console if there is any content.

Comment: i have tried your code and now i get another error:" Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream' "

Comment: Does the xml variable contain the correct string? If yes, you have to [convert the string into a stream](http://www.csharp411.com/c-convert-string-to-stream-and-stream-to-string/).